# Not able make conference call in Motoroal MOTO E

Tags: calls, motorola-moto-e

When i tried to make a conference call in Motorola MOTO E it is not allowing.

While giving the merge call option it says "Conference call is not allowed".

please clear my doubt  whether MOTO E supports Conference call facility or not .

Answer (score 2):

That message tells you that conference calling is not allowed **by your carrier**; it's not that the phone doesn't support it. You need to contact your carrier to enable this feature.